# Using becomeFirstResponder on a new UITextField

Tags: objective-c, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I am trying to programmatically set the focus on a new UITextField that I created using becomeFirstResponder. Is there any other way?

```
-(void) editPlayerName
{
    lblPLayerName.visible = FALSE;

    NSString* fontNm = @"Chalkduster";

    tfPlayerName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,20,200,24)];
    tfPlayerName.text = [myS playerName];
    tfPlayerName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    tfPlayerName.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    tfPlayerName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontNm size:20];
    tfPlayerName.delegate = self;

    UIView* glView = [CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView;
    [glView addSubview:tfPlayerName];

    [tfPlayerName becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `becomeFirstResponder`?

Comment: Nothing. It just seemed odd to me. Just wondering if this was the proper way.

Comment: Yes, `becomeFirstResponder` is the proper way to do this.